# Value saved to database with a comma

Tags: html, razor, webmatrix

When I run the following code it always saves the `TeamID` with a comma at the end. `FirstName` and `LastName` save perfectly, but not `TeamID`.

```
<div class="form-group">

<select class="form-control" name="" >
    <div>@foreach(var Team in MyTeam){
        <option value="">@Team.FirstName @Team.LastName</option>
            <input type="hidden" name="FirstName" value=@Team.FirstName>
            <input type="hidden" name="LastName" value=@Team.LastName>    
            <input type="hidden" name="TeamID" value=@Team.UserID>    
    }
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the value of `UserID` you get? Also, you need quotes `"` around the values.

Comment: Also, you have a `div` inside your `select` tag that's not closed (and I'm pretty sure is not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the "div" was in the wrong place. Problem fixed - thanks to @Steve for helping me see that:

```
<select class="form-control" name="">
     <div>@foreach(var Team in MyTeam){
            <option value="">@Team.FirstName @Team.LastName</option>
            <input type="hidden" name="FirstName" value=@Team.FirstName>
            <input type="hidden" name="LastName" value=@Team.LastName>    
            <input type="hidden" name="TeamID" value=@Team.UserID> 
       }
     </div>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. The form I had on the page already had a Team update. Fixed by removing it.